# Most convenient way to transfer files between the local machine and the remote

Tags: ubuntu, scp

`scp`'ing every single time I need to have a small file copied when working on some remote server is quite tiring.

What other solutions do we have? Which one is the most convenient?

Preferably something that:

- does not require a complex setup on either side (assume both machines are a modern Ubuntu)
- opens some sort of a persistent connection, so there's as little typing needed for subsequent transfers

(Maybe a continuously syncing FTP server?)

Comment: Are you copying a text file or a binary?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Both, but I guess a binary can be made into text with base64

Comment: Have you come across sshfs? It's trivial to install on an Ubuntu client machine and requires no setup at all on the server as it uses ssh / sftp.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Thanks, looking into sshfs / nfs right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe a continuously syncing FTP server?

FTP is [not recommended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie). The
protocol has many problems and [Debian](https://www.debian.org/news/2017/20170425) and
[kernel](https://www.kernel.org/shutting-down-ftp-services.html) shut
down their FTP services a few years ago.
There are 2 solutions to your problem:

If you are editing text files you should first check if an editor you
use comes with feature that would allow you to edit files
remotely. [Emacs TRAMP](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) is
an example of such feature.

If you're copying binaries or use an editor that doesn't allow you to
edit files remotely you can mount a remote server locally using sshfs
like that (you don't need to be root):

```
$ mkdir ~/ssh-mount
$ sshfs <your-ssh-server>: ~/ssh-mount
```

Home directory of user you use to connect to the remote server will be
mounted at ~/ssh-mount directory. You can explicitly specify a
directory you want to mount after `:`. Depending on what you're doing
you can now either open the files in your editor normally as you would
open local files or instruct your compiler to save output binaries in
ssh-mount dir, for example by specifying `-o ~/ssh-mount` option in
gcc.

You also don't to be root to unmount the directory:

```
$ fusermount -u ~/ssh-mount
```

Notice that not all SSH servers implement sshfs - OpenSSH does but
Dropbear for example does not.